# Facebook Broadcast api required both page & app level messaging permissions?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

while sending broadcast I am getting this error ->

{
"error": {
"message": "(#230) Requires pages_messaging_subscriptions permission to manage the object",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 230,
"fbtrace_id": "FT08BkMAM77"
}
}

from api "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/broadcast_messages".

Do I need both page level `subscription_messaging_permission` as well as App level `pages_messaging_subscriptions` permission for broadcast?

FYI - My page has subscription_messaging_permission still I am getting above error.

TIA

## broadcast

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution? I described my case here: https://www.facebook.com/groups/messengerplatform/permalink/666786900364956/

Comment: Have filed a bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1887634887939334/?legacy_version=true till then lets wait